# Google Secure LDAP credentials not working

Tags: ldap, google-sso

I'm trying to get a simple `ldapsearch` query working against Google Secure LDAP **without** using client certificate. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 `ldap-utils`.
Am I doing something obviously wrong with my query below? Assume username generated by Google is `LDAPUser1` and password is `RAND123` and my domain is `example.com`:

```
ldapsearch -D "LDAPUser1" -w RAND123 -b "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -H ldaps://ldap.google.com:636
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following error:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: Incorrect password
```

I've copied the username and password verbatum from the Google Secure LDAP "Access Credentials" section.  It's directly below the "Certificates" section.